# This routing code is not working

Tags: angularjs

This code is not working properly

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : '/index.html',
    controller  : 'HomeController'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl : '/about.html',
    controller  : 'AboutController'
  })

  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from HomeController';
});

app.controller('AboutController', function($scope) {
  $scope.message = 'Hello from AboutController';
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you expect ?

Comment: **Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: Take a few minutes also to read [ask] and [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it is difficult to say exactly what the problem is. But, I can tell you this:

*index.html* should almost NEVER appear in one of your routes. This is because index.html is your home page and contains the tag:

```
    <!-- Place where our view will be displayed -->
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
```

For example, the body of your index.html might look like this:

```
<body ng-app="routingApp">
    <header>
        <a href="#/home">Home</a>
        <a href="#/about">About</a>
    </header>
    <!-- Place where our view will be displayed -->
    <div ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
```

Notice that instead of using index.html in your route, you should use a Home route like this:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : '/home.html',
    controller  : 'HomeController'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl : '/about.html',
    controller  : 'AboutController'
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});
```